# External USB hard drive is read only but I want r/w

Tags: linux, mount, centos

I recently formatted a hard drive as ext3 to get it to mount in CentOS 5. Now it automatically mounts when I connect it to the USB port, and mounts to /media/disk, but i am not able to write to it.

here is the output of my mount command:

```
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00 on / type ext3 (rw,acl,usrquota,grpquota)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
/dev/sdc1 on /boot type ext3 (rw)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
/dev/mapper/vg_epa1-lv_root on /lv_root type ext4 (rw,acl)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
epa2:/shares/epa2 on /shares/epa2 type nfs (rw,acl,hard,intr,addr=172.31.10.19)
nemo:/shares/nemo on /shares/nemo type nfs (rw,acl,hard,intr,addr=172.31.10.20)
nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw)
/dev/sde1 on /media/disk type ext3 (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
```

The last one is my external drive. it is showing as rw, so how come I cant put files on it?

Comment: What happens when you try to write files to it?  What are the permissions on the target drive/folder?

Comment: I can't even make a target folder on the drive. it returns "mkdir: cannot create directory `test': Permission denied".  The permissions in /media/disk are drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Dec 19 11:49 .

Comment: It appears that only "root" has write permissions. Are you the "root" user?  Does it work if you change permissions to (say) 777?

Comment: Didnt realize you needed to change permissions to wide open. I was root on both systems, but I formatted on one system, and used it on another

Comment: It's not that you NEED to change them to wide-open, I suggested it for the sake of testing/troubleshooting. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using kde you probably need to dig into policykit options I think. I had similar problem, and changing permissions with that helped me.